# Lodash debounce isn't preventing dispatch as expected onChange

Tags: reactjs, debouncing

Currently, I have a list of checkboxes that onChange will make a request to the server to return some data. However, I am using lodash debounce to try and make a request only when the user has stopped selecting the multi-checkbox after a certain amount of time.

Currently, it prevents dispatching straight away but will dispatch after the debounce time has met rather when the user has stopped interacting with the checkboxes. Can someone tell me how I would achieve this or where I am going wrong?

Thanks!

```js
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Context } from '../../pages/search-and-results/search-and-results.js';
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';

const FilterCheckbox = ({ name, value }) => {
  const checkboxContext = useContext(Context);
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const debounceCheckboxSelection = debounce(dispatchCheckbox, 2000);

  function dispatchCheckbox(type, value) {
    checkboxContext.dispatch({
      type: type,
      payload: { value }
    });
  }

  return (
    <Label>
      <FilterInput
        type="checkbox"
        name={name}
        onChange={() => {
          if (checked) {
            debounceCheckboxSelection('REMOVE_SELECTED_PROPERTY_TYPE', value);
            setChecked(false);
            return;
          }
          debounceCheckboxSelection('SET_SELECTED_PROPERTY_TYPE', value);
          setChecked(true);
        }}
        checked={checked}
      />
      {name}
    </Label>
  );
};

export default FilterCheckbox;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your debounced function is getting created at each re-render, to fix it:

You can use [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) which returns a ref object which will persist for the full lifetime of the component:

```
const debounceCheckboxSelection = useRef(
  debounce(dispatchCheckbox, 2000);
)
```

and access its initial value with `debounceCheckboxSelection.current`:

```
<FilterInput
  type="checkbox"
  name={name}
  onChange={() => {
    if (checked) {
      debounceCheckboxSelection.current('REMOVE_SELECTED_PROPERTY_TYPE', value);
      setChecked(false);
      return;
    }
    debounceCheckboxSelection.current('SET_SELECTED_PROPERTY_TYPE', value);
    setChecked(true);
  }}
  checked={checked}
/>
```

Or you can use [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) will returns a memoized version of the callback that only changes when any of its dependencies change:

```
const debounceCheckboxSelection = useCallback(
  () => debounce(dispatchCheckbox, 2000), []
)
```

Comment: Hi @Ajeet,

Thank you very much for your response, I have tried to implement the changes you mentioned above, for some reason it still seems to dispatch after the debounce time has been met rather than when the user has stopped checking/unchecking. :(

Comment: `dispatchCheckbox` will get called after 2 seconds of `onChange` event on the checkbox. If user changes the checkbox selection before 2 seconds, `dispatchCheckbox` will get called after 2 seconds of the 2nd onChange. Isn't it working this way?

Comment: It seems to get called after 2 seconds regardless if you keep selecting multiple checkboxes quickly, it seems to dispatch and ignore the debounce by the looks of it?

Comment: Sure, let me mock one up - thank you very much for helping me out thus far!

Comment: *"but will dispatch after the debounce time has met rather when the user has stopped interacting with the checkboxes"*: Seems like your problem was something else and I misread it and fixed some other problem. You are looking for event - **when user is done** with checkboxes. But I think there is no way to know when "user is done with checkboxes".

Comment: So you don't think it's possible to achieve what I am hoping for?

Comment: I am not 100% sure that you are really looking for an event **when the user is done with the form**. Now tell me, how can we know if user is done or not, (*it is in user's mind*). The user might stay and just look at the form for 5 minutes and think (I am not done, lets make one more change in the form), so even 5 minutes can't be considered as **Done with Form**. Am I inline with your thoughts about your question or going in different direction? You can provide a **Submit** button, and user can click on that button when they will be **done**.

Comment: You're right. I think I will go with your suggestion of a 'Save' button of some sort, which would make things much easier - thank you ever so much for helping me out Ajeet. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

```
   <input onChange={_.debounce((e)=> dispatch(search(e.target.value)), 300)} />
```

Can do something like this and remember to import the lodash and dispatch