# What is the best way to get items from a search API?

Tags: reactjs, api, github

I have a React app which fetches Github repositories with Github search API, the function looks like this;

```
 const searchEverything = (input: string) => {
    if (input.length > 2) {
      setSearchPageStatus(true);
      fetch(`https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=${input}`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          setRepoCount(data.total_count);
          setRepos(data.items);
        });

      fetch(`https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${input}`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          setUserCount(data.total_count);
          setUsers(data.items);
        });
    } else {
      setSearchPageStatus(false);
    }
  };
```

So I get items with "onChange" attribute like this;

```
<input onChange={(e) => searchEverything(e.target.value)}
       type="search"
       className="header__search__input"
        placeholder="Search..."
        />
```

I am not getting errors or anything like that. But as  you can see on each key stroke there is an API call and I feel like it's not efficent and if you have a long word there might be an error 403. So is there any better way to use this API ? The solution I thought is just putting a button and searching after click but it just takes away all the dynamism.

Comment: You can use [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce). Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23123138/2873538), you will find many examples. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24004791/2873538) to understand the debounce. Here is an answer about how to not **re-create** a new [debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62213046/2873538) at each render.

Comment: Please check the preview of the 403 message if it is a authentication issue

Comment: @İlker can you check this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`throttle`](https://underscorejs.org/#throttle) or [`debounce`](https://underscorejs.org/#debounce) to limit the number of times a function is called.

You don't need to use `_`, can write your own if you want.