# React/Next - My debounce callback is not being fired correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, debouncing

So I want to trigger a debounce on change of a text input.

Here is my code..
Component with text searchbar:

```
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useState('');
  const [searchResponse, setSearchResponse] = useState(null);

  const dataFetch = async (params) => {
    console.log('fetching data');
    console.log('heres the param: ', params);
    fetch('/api/DebounceTest', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ query: params }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => data)
      .then((moreData) => console.log(moreData))
      .catch((e) => console.error(e));
  };

  // dataFetch = debounce(dataFetch, 1000);

  const callDebounce = (params) => {
    debounce(() => {
      dataFetch(params);
    }, 250);
  };

  const onSearchParamChanged = React.useCallback((params) => {
    callDebounce(params);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    onSearchParamChanged(searchParams);
  }, [searchParams]);
```

Here is my debounce:

```
  let timer;
  return function () {
    console.log('meow');
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('calling function');
      fn();
    }, delay);
  };
};
```

Basically whats going on is that the debounce is not calling the callback at all when the timer resolves. There are no errors. I thought maybe I could add a `()` after the debounce cal in callDebounce like this:

```
  const callDebounce = (params) => {
    debounce(() => {
      dataFetch(params);
    }, 250)();
  };
```

but react will throw the error
"Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Object(...)(...) is not a function"
And it points to the debounce call that i just mentioned.

Any info helps. Thank you.

Comment: You should use useCallback hook : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62213046/2873538

Comment: Here's a live-search demo using a custom useAsyncEffect hook that might be helpful for your challenge [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-async-effect-axios-rickmorty-search-ui-sd2mv?file=/src/TestComponent.js)